# how to add link to sidebar on app page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a facebook app and on the page that has the apps wall and info , I was wanting to add custom tabs on there that go to different pages within the actual app

eg, when I go to http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=143227092412617 I see the wall and info on the sidebar, but I cannot figure out how to add more links on there.

What I want to do is add links on the sidebar on there to things like the support page for the app (eg. http://apps.facebook.com/towers_wordgame/support.html) so that on the sidebar it reads WALL, INFO, SUPPORT

is this able to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do a Canvas App. Here's a tutorial posted by Facebook themselves.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

If you want to create a tab on a page you can have a look at this link instead.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/